# Casting array to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, casting

Assume you have a basic `Employee` class as such:

```
class Employee
{
   public string Name;
   public int Years;
   public string Department;
}
```

Then (in a seperate class) I have the following code fragments (I think i understand all but the last):

I believe that the following code fragment works because the array initiliser creates an array of Employee objects which are the same type as the workforce variable being assigned to.

```
Employee[] workforceOne = new Employee[] {
   new Employee() { Name = "David", Years = 0, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Dexter", Years = 3, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Paul", Years = 4, Department = "software" } };
```

I then have the following code fragment.  I believe this works because the array of `Employee` objects implicity is an implementation of the Array() class which implements `IEnumerable`.  Therefore, I believe this is why the array can be assigned to IEnumerable?

```
IEnumerable workforceTwo = new Employee[] {
   new Employee() { Name = "David", Years = 0, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Dexter", Years = 3, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Paul", Years = 4, Department = "software" } };
```

Then I have this code fragment:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> workforceThree = new Employee[] {
   new Employee() { Name = "David", Years = 0, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Dexter", Years = 3, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Paul", Years = 4, Department = "software" } };
```

**I am not sure why this code fragment works?**  `IEnumerable<Employee>` inherits from `IEnumerable` (and overrides (or overloads?) the `GetEnumerator()` method) but shouldn't i therefore need a cast for the above to work as such:

```
//The cast does work but is not required
IEnumerable<Employee> workforceFour = (IEnumerable<Employee>)new Employee[] {
   new Employee() { Name = "David", Years = 0, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Dexter", Years = 3, Department = "software" },
   new Employee() { Name = "Paul", Years = 4, Department = "software" } };
```

It seems that the array is being implicitly down cast from a type of `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<Employee>` but I always thought when you needed to convert a type to something more specific you needed an explicit cast.

Maybe i'm missing something simple in my understanding here but can someone please help me with my understanding around this.

Thank you.

Comment: @Aliostad: It's right below the `workforceThree` fragment.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> In the .NET Framework version 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class, and there are no reference topics for interface members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type (explicit interface implementations).

Thus, your `Employee[]` implements `IEnumerable<Employee>`.

Comment: To clarify, it is not the Array class that implements it, it's T[] of any T.

Answer (score 6):

The Array of Employees by default implements `IEnumerable<Employee>` as well  as `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 3):

Explicit cast is needed when some sentence needs to be *downcasted*. That's casting an object to a more specialized type - if the object is of such specialized type -.

In the other hand, *upcasting* (casting to a less specialized type), will never need an explicit cast, but you can explicitly do it (it's just useless).

Since Array implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>`, you're doing an **upcast** in your code, meaning _you don't need to explicitly cast to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I'm not agree. In some case you need an explicit upcast. As an example function override :

void DoStuffs(IEnumerable<T> objects) { ... }

void DoStuffs(params T[] objects) { DoStuffs((IEnumerable<T>) objects); }

Comment: @Orace This isn't exactly an upcast... It's a compiler help to let it invoke the desired overload... are you agree? ;) It's a method overload resolution issue.

Comment: @Orace Well, it's an upcast, but I mean that you need the explicit "cast" to invoke the desired overload...