# Modify multi Dimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an Array variable. I can use the Rank property to get the number of dimensions and I know that you can use a foreach to visit each element as if the array was flattened. However, I wish to modify elements and change element references. I cannot dynamically create the correct number of for loops and I cannot invalidate an enumerator.

**EDIT**
Thanks for the comments, sorry about the previous lack of clarity at the end of a long tiring day. The problem:

```
private void SetMultiDimensionalArray(Array array)
{
    for (int dimension = 0;  dimension < array.Rank;   dimension++)
    {
        var len = array.GetLength(dimension);
        for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)
        {
            //TODO: do something to get/set values
        }
     }
}

Array array = new string[4, 5, 6];
SetMultiDimensionalArray(array);
Array array = new string[2, 3];
SetMultiDimensionalArray(array);
```

I had another look before reading this page and it appears all I need to do is create a list of integer arrays and use the overloads of GetValue and SetValue -

```
Array.GetValue(params int[] indices)
Array.SetValue(object value, params int[] indices)
```

Everything seems clear now unless someone can suggest a superior method. svick has linked to this so I will accept this answer barring any further suggestions.

Comment: This would be easier to conceptualize if I could see some code.

Comment: Sure will edit the question but not until tomorrow now thx

Comment: Arrays in c# implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  What is the problem exactly?
See this post for a good description - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173266/casting-array-to-ienumerablet

Comment: The title of your question is confusing. In C#, multidimensional array (e.g. `int[,]`) is different from jagged array (e.g. `int[][]`). From your description, it looks like you're dealing with the former, is that right?

Comment: @svick you were right, not a jagged array.

Comment: You can post your solution as a self-answer and accept it, just to close the books here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what exactly do you need, because your question is quite unclear.

But if you have a multidimensional array (not jagged array) whose rank you know only at runtime, you can use [`GetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2cf72s5.aspx) to get the value at specified indices (given as an array of `int`s) and [`SetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/758awxk7.aspx) to set it.