# Why does casting a value as IEnumerable<T> behave differently based on how I initialized the value?

Tags: c#, casting

I have some code that takes a value (of type object) and tries to cast it to an IEnumerable of ints and uints like so:

```
var idList = value as IEnumerable<int>;
var uintList = value as IEnumerable<uint>;
```

When the value is initialized this way:

```
uint number = 1;
object value = new []{ number };
```

both idList and uintList have values, but calling idList.ToList() results in an `ArrayTypeMismatchException`. However, when the value is generated with `new List<uint>{ number }`, idList is null as expected.

Additionally, calling `var idList = value as IEnumerable<int>;` in the immediate window in VS 2015 returns null as I would expect, even when the value was generated with a collection initializer.

[.Net fiddle reproducing the error here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z8LYUL).

What's going on here?

Comment: You might look at this stack overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173266/casting-array-to-ienumerablet

Comment: If you I initialize `value` as you have then the line `var idList = value as IEnumerable<int>;` gives me a compile-time error, not an runtime exception

Comment: Hm, no compile errors here, but I realized that in simplifying the code path I left out that value has been cast to an object type before it gets cast back to an IEnumerable. Will add that to the question accordingly, thanks.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that you're trying to do an implicit conversion from an `IEnumerable<uint>` to an `IEnumerable<int>`.  Because these are IEnumerables, I think they're being evaluated lazily.  When you call `ToList` your forcing an evaluation of the object.  Note also that there's no implicit conversion from a uint to an int.  uint.MaxValue is twice int.MaxValue.  uint.MinValue is of course zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's because of unusual differences between how C# and CLR treats conversions between `int` and `uint`, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/593799/5311735). First note that this code won't compile:

```
uint[] a1 = new[] { 1u };
var a2 = (int[])a1;
```

Because C# doesn't believe there exists a cast. However if you go this way:

```
uint[] a1 = new[] { 1u };
var a2 = (int[]) (object) a1;
```

Runtime will decide if this cast is valid or not, and it (CLR) thinks differently and allows casting from `uint[]` to `int[]` (and visa versa), as desribed in answer I linked.

But the same is not true for `List<int>` and `List<uint>` - they are not treated in a special way by CLR and as such cannot be cast between each other.

So in your case, `uint[]` can be cast to `int[]` and `int[]` implements `IEnumerable<int>`, so your `idList` is not null. This is not true for Lists - hence your problem.

As for why ToList fails in first case, that's because internally it does something like that:

```
 uint[] a1 = new[] { 1u };
 var a2 = (int[]) (object) a1;
 // ToList copies contents to new array
 int[] copy = new int[a2.Length];
 Array.Copy(a2, copy, a2.Length);
```

And `Array.Copy` checks directly if type of elements in one array are compatible with type of elements in another array.

Comment: That's really weird, thanks for explaining! I wouldn't expect the CLR and language to disagree either, but :shrug: